# Are there any useful tools to mirror a mailman mailing list as a forum?

Tags: forum, mailing-list, integration, mirror

We have a mailman mailing list however as we all know this is not very user friendly in terms of searching the archives.

I am looking at a way to enable the continued functionality of mailman while having a forum linked to it for a more friendly user-interface approach.

Is there a forum application that lets you mirror the mailman service so that posts to mailman are sync'd into the forum and posts to the forum are sync'd to mailman?

Comment: Now there is a new option -- use [Mailman 3](http://wiki.list.org/DEV/Mailman%203.0). Mailman 3 provides a forum archive viewer [HyperKitty](http://wiki.list.org/HyperKitty) (which can also work as a standalone forum). Here is a [demo](https://lists.stg.fedoraproject.org/archives/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mail2Forum](http://mail2forum.com/) is known to work well with Mailman and PHPBB. I believe it can also handle other systems like VBulletin, I'm not sure about Vanilla.

I've never installed it, but I have dug through forums that used it to do what you are describing. I believe it also does a good job of handling attachments, if the forum is configured to support them.

Note: Don't expect perfect ordering in message threads, whatever way you go if users can sort replies by *their* time. You can expect some messages to be dated 'tomorrow', depending on the usage of the list.

Answer (score 2):

[mail2forum](http://mail2forum.com/) for phpBB seems pretty much dead right now, alongside with Drupal's solution [Listhandler](https://drupal.org/project/listhandler). Google groups did offer similar functionality through [Remote Archives](https://support.google.com/groups/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=46387), but that's not available in the new Google Groups UI anymore (though can still be used by now through the old UI).
FUDForum still seems to support [mailing list integration](http://cvs.prohost.org/index.php/Mailing_List_Manager).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to host it yourself, you could look at [Nabble](http://n3.nabble.com/archive-your-mailing-list.html).

For self-hosting, the only one I've run across is [FUDforum](http://fudforum.org/forum/), an open source PHP forum, but there must be others...

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Tiki CMS](http://info.tiki.org/) it offers such a functionality and works quite good.

More info and instructions [here](http://doc.tiki.org/Forum+and+Mailing+List+Synchronization).